# NUnit is executing All If statement evenif the condition fails

Tags: nunit

I am executing If statement based on some vales but Nunit executes all statements even if the condition is false

Comment: Could you show the code please?

Comment: -1 as the question doesn't provide any information to go on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunit doesn't actually evaluate your statements, it simply instantiates your tests and runs them.  I would suggest that you install [TestDriven.NET](http://testdriven.net), if you haven't already, and use the right-click test runner in your test to run it with the debugger.  Set some breakpoints in your code and look at the values that will be evaluated for the if statement.  I expect, with @Joe90, that the error is in your code, not Nunit.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit is written entirely in C#, if statements do work in C#! :)

It must be a mistake in your implementation or interpretation.